# Stored Procedure with ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a need to sync auto_increment fields between two tables in different databases on the same MySQL server. The hope was to create a stored procedure where the permissions of the admin would let the web user run `ALTER TABLE [db1].[table] AUTO_INCREMENT = [num];` without giving it permissions (That just smells of SQL injection).

My problem is I'm receiving errors when creating the store procedure. Is this something that is not allowed by MySQL?

`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sync_auto_increment;

CREATE PROCEDURE set_auto_increment (tableName VARCHAR(64), inc INT)

BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = inc;

END;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you need to change the delimiter. It thinks that the `Alter table` line is the end of the function. Try this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sync_auto_increment;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE set_auto_increment (tableName VARCHAR(64), inc INT)
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = inc;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Sometimes mysql is still picky about letting you use stored procedures, so you can do try this if you still can't run it:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sync_auto_increment;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE set_auto_increment (tableName VARCHAR(64), inc INT)
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = inc;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Oh, And I don't think that you can actually use a variable for a table name, so you may have to make different procedures for each table you want to alter...

Comment: I had actually removed the delimiter for brevity.

I tried both your examples and am still getting the following error.
<code>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inc; END' at line 5</code>

Comment: Wait, you can't use variables for table name, at all?!?
I had heard that it might be possible using prepared statements. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: Well, the MsSQL Manual gives the example: `PREPARE stmt_name FROM "SELECT name FROM Country WHERE code = ?";`. This is the first I've heard of them though. I tried `PREPARE tmp_stmt FROM "SELECT * FROM ? LIMIT 10";` And It gave me the same error. SO, it looks like prepared statements (in my brief attempt, anyway) won't work either. I was setting up procedures to do something to 3 tables with the same structure, and I ended up having to write in:
`IF (tablename = 'table_name_1') THEN
 SELECT * FROM table_name_1`
And another `If` for two other tables. I suppose it works... but it's not great.

Answer (score 5):

To extend on the discussion on the comments on [Chibu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278918/chibu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2520337/402022)... yes, you can use prepared statements. But you got to use `CONCAT` to create the sentence instead of using `PREPARE ... FROM ...`.

Here is a working solution:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS set_auto_increment;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE set_auto_increment (_table VARCHAR(64), _inc INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _stmt VARCHAR(1024);
    SET @SQL := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', _table, ' AUTO_INCREMENT =  ', _inc);
    PREPARE _stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE _stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _stmt;
END//
DELIMITER;
```

---

I've learned this form the article [Prepared Statement Failure](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/01/19/prepared-statement-failure/) by Michael McLaughlin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find you can't put Data Definition Language statements into a stored procedure. A possible exception would be CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE. I have searched the MySQL manual for more information on that point; it says the stored procedure may contain a statement_list, but nowhere defines what that means. But I think that's the case.